# CAS: Decryption of TGT

Tags: encryption, cas

I want to decrypt my TGT at a client. I know that the key that I generated is a so called `octet sequence` key. What is the algorithm to decrypt it or what are C++ libraries to help me doing that?

Answer (score 1):

The TGT is an opaque String only the CAS server knows to what identity it is related. What's your need?

Comment: I have desktop applications in my CAS environment. I want that the TGT is encrypted when it is saved in the cookie DB of my browser. My desktop application used the RESTful API, therefore I cant just send the encrypted TGT to the CAS-Server, so I need to decrypt it on my CAS client before sending it.

Comment: Since I created the TGT encryption and signing keys myself, I thought I can use them to decrypt them by using the same algorithm the CAS server uses

Comment: I would not pass the TGT, which represents a user identity. To access an applicaton (your desktop one), you should pass a service ticket you validate on the CAS server.

Comment: Yes, but I have to request a ST with my TGT, right? So I have to pass the TGT to get the ST.